# How to configure Proguard to do not modify anything

Tags: java, gradle, proguard

I have a complex java application that uses libraries like spring boot, apache, etc. All class, application and libraries are package into a big jar with a gradle task "fatJar".

Then I would like to optimize and shrink code using a proguard gradle task, the task seems to execute, but the resulting jar not.

I would like to configure proguard in order to do not modify anything, just to copy all as it is, check the new jar works, and after that, let proguard modify classes little by little, checking in each step that the resulting jar works.

I am using options like

```
dontshrink
dontoptimize
keep 'class *.**  { *; }'
```

but proguard continues modifying class files and final jar doesn`t work.
Which options could be used to avoid proguard modifying files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think `dontobfuscate` might belong there too (I'd answer but I'm not sure about the subtleties).

Comment: Just checking - in your pasted sample code you have `dontshrink`, but the proguard config requires `-dontshrink` with a `-` in front of it (same for the other directives). Is that `-` missing just from your question or also from your proguard file?